# NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT Relay access denied on AWS ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, smtp, postfix-mta, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Postfix on AWS ubuntu(18.04).
When I am trying to send email from my EmailId to configured postfix mail server i.e ceo@visitormanagementsystem.co.in, getting below log:

> Sep 30 15:12:05 mailer postfix/smtpd[17712]: connect from
>   mail-pg1-f178.google.com[209.85.215.178] Sep 30 15:12:06 mailer
>   postfix/smtpd[17712]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
>   mail-pg1-f178.google.com[209.85.215.178]: 454 4.7.1
>   : Relay access denied;
>   from= to=
>   proto=ESMTP helo=

My /etc/postfix/mail.cf has following configuration:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name ($mail_version)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = + .
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mailer.visitormanagementsystem.co.in
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mailer.visitormanagementsystem.co.in, localhost.visitormanagementsystem.co.in, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only defining how users can relay through your postfix instance, not how you can receive mail.  You'll need to configure the other smtpd transport types to ensure mail can be delivered.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions
smtpd_client_restrictions
smtpd_sender_restrictions
```

Comment: I forgot to mention my apex domain name i.e **visitormanagementsystem.co.in** In mydestination parameter. I am able to receive mail after adding my domain name without any smtpd transport.

Comment: If you have domains you want to reject delivery from (for example domains that spam a lot) you'll still want to configure `smtpd_client_restrictions` as one method to limit who you receive mail from.